# java thread problem

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I wrote a simple program with java swing which suppose to start another thread and in that thread a JForm will show up when I click a button. But JForm is not showing up... I used `if (Thread.currentThread().getName() == "Thread1")` to do the specific task for that thread, when I comment that program runs perfectly, I can't understand why it is not going to the if block... Please someone help me with this...

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code,

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JPanel panel;
JButton button;

public Test() {

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    button = new JButton("click me");

    button.addActionListener(this);

    panel.add(button);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test tst=new Test();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getSource()==button){
        System.out.println("test");
    test2 test = new test2();
    Thread tr1 = new Thread(test);      
    tr1.setName("Thread1");
    tr1.start();
    }

}
}

class test2 implements Runnable{


public void run() {
    //if (Thread.currentThread().getName() == "Thread1") {
        System.out.println("inside thread");
        JFrame frame2=new JFrame();
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setSize(300, 300);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    //}     
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `getName().equals("Thread1")` instead.

`equals` compares the strings, `==` checks if the two strings are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1"))
```

or

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getName().compareTo("Thread1") > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. why do you have that check for the current threads name anyway? That thread will be the only one to call that method anyway.
2. You must not compare `String` values using `==` as it checks for object identity. You should use `Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1")` instead.
3. You should not interact with any Swing/AWT components outside of the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)!